# JQuery Autofill - Make Mandatory Selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-autocomplete

I used JQuery Autocomplete component to show the values from database. In this, the user can select  the item by typing some text. In case, if the user not select any of the options shown below, the field is filled with value which user typed. But I want make that field such way that user can only select the value listed in Autocomplete. It should not contain any typed text.  Is there any possible way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes possible.

1)  Using [**`change`**](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-change) event you can clear the textbox values if no options are selected.

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
          source: availableTags,
          change: function (event, ui) {
              if (!ui.item) {
                  $(this).val("");
                  // Handle the error
              } 
          }
      });
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/689Uf/4/)

2) Not sure, have you been aware of [autocomplete-combo], this suits for your issue.(http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox)

Comment: Awesome.. Change function itself solve my problem... Thank you.. we can acheive this with Combobox but using autofill is my requirement..

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try out [Selectize](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/)

on that site Search for "Max Items" this will fulfill your requirment
It allow you to only select from whatever in the list

Comment: Thank you for responding.. I can only using jquery ui component.. Not any other libraries.. Praveen's answer solves the issue..Thank you..